# ORDER BY alphabet first then follow by number

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I looking for some tweak in mysql ordering , I normally select record from table and then order the record by Name(varchar) ASC **but the number is always come first**

here some example of my question (*note. mysql sort the record with 0-9 first*)

```
SELECT name FROM list ORDER BY name ASC
record returned:
1 star
2 star
9 slice
Ape
Age
Beg
Bell
Fish
Zoo
```

**What i want is the alphabet order come first then follow by number**

Desired output

```
Ape
Age
Beg
Bell
Fish
Zoo
1 star
2 star
9 slice
```

Comment: I tried to make question simple and neat , please let me know if i should provide more information , cheers !

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the following `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY IF(name RLIKE '^[a-z]', 1, 2), name
```

Comment: `RLIKE` or LIKE **?** didn't get

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan R stand for regex

Comment: Wow!! It saved my lot of time. Thank you so much :)

Comment: How do you sort descending? Eg. 9,2,1, Zoo,Fish,Bell?

Comment: Add `DESC`: `ORDER BY IF(name RLIKE '[a-z]'), 1, 2) DESC, name DESC`

Answer (score 10):

Ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055049/how-to-order-mysql-varchar-results)

```
SELECT name FROM list ORDER BY name * 1 ASC
```

Edited

```
SELECT name FROM list ORDER BY name * 1, name ASC
```

Comment: That ignores all the letters.

Comment: @barmar:- yes, agree with you

Comment: This worked for me. Barmar's answer for some reason did not

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    name 
FROM 
    list 
ORDER BY 
    IF(name REGEXP '^[0-9]', CONCAT('zz',name),name) ASC
```

So if your name start with a digit you concatenate 'zz' in the beginning (so that it will be last)

Comment: Won't that make numbers go between `v` and `w`?

Comment: @Barmar your right... i meant to put the last letter of the alphabet but even so it will not solve all the cases like when you have a name : 'zzabc'

Comment: Which is why my solution is best.

Comment: Nice hack too , but i'm working on a large dictionary table , so i'll will stick to @Barmar solution , anyway thanks!

Comment: yes , we can all agree that the best/cleanest solution was offered by @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in Rails with a POSTGRESQL DB

```
.order(Arel.sql("SUBSTRING(LOWER(name), '^[A-Za-z].*'), SUBSTRING(LOWER(name), '^[0-9]+')::FLOAT"))
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this..

It simple one to get your answer

```
SELECT name  from list ORDER BY (name +0) ASC ,name ASC
```