# Complex MySQL ORDERing: 'the' and punctuation ignored, plus numbers last

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Long time reader, first-time question...er.

I'm refactoring and upgrading some incredibly old PHP and MySQL queries (through PDO) at the moment, and have come across a very complex ordering requirement that I can't get right.

I have a table listing titles. Let's say they're books. I need to get a list of all those titles out in order to list them under different tabs according to their first letter. The ordering requirements are as follows:

1. Ignore leading 'the' (not necessary for 'a' or 'an')
2. Ignore leading punctuation
3. Place numbers last

E.g.

- A Tale of Two Cities
- The Adventures of Tom Sawyer
- Charlie and the Chocolate Factory
- @hotmail.com: A Terror Story from 2002
- 'No' - Standing Your Ground
- The Picture of Dorian Gray
- War and Peace
- The 8th Dwarf
- 1000 Years of Annoying the French

All three are easy. 1 & 2 I can do together without any trouble - albeit with a mucky list of specific punctuation, rather than a catch-all (regex maybe?). 3 I can do alone thanks to previous question '[ORDER BY alphabet first then follow by number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418215/order-by-alphabet-first-then-follow-by-number)'; but I can't get all three working at the same time.

Implementing requirements 1 and 2, the query as it stands is as follows:

```
SELECT title FROM books WHERE discontinued=0 ORDER BY TRIM(LEADING " " FROM TRIM(LEADING "!" FROM TRIM(LEADING "@" FROM TRIM(LEADING "'" FROM TRIM(LEADING "(" FROM TRIM(LEADING "..." FROM TRIM(LEADING "%" FROM TRIM(LEADING "The " FROM title)))))))) ASC, year_of_publication ASC
```

- Firstly and primarily, can anyone help me get all 3 working at the same time?
- Secondly, bearing in mind that 'The' and all the punctuation is left in tact in the `title` values that are returned to my PHP, can anyone suggest a nice way to then split up the records as I iterate through them in PHP, in order to populate the 27 A-Z and # tabs? A virtual column listing the first character that SQL **is** sorting on, perhaps? *(The code I'm refactoring achieved this by running 27 queries (!), for titles starting with each letter in turn - not something I want to do if I can avoid it!)*
- Thirdly, is there a neater way of trimming leading punctuation from the title than listing them individually? *(Not so important, but if it makes nicer/more efficient code...)*
- Fourth and finally, if anyone could throw in a way to order those numbers 1, 2, 3 ... 10 rather than 1, 10, 2, 3, that would also be appreciated. *(Again, I've seen this 'natural sort' implemented in simpler queries, but not with something like this. It's not important, but nice if it's possible alongside all the rest of my requirements!)*

Any thoughts, help or advice in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated and gratefully received! Happy, of course, to try going about it a different way if that's what it takes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Natural Sort in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql)

Comment: I would suggest you make a separate column ie `sort_title`, do all your transformations on that column on insert or update and make sure it has a full text index on it.  What you are trying to do with each query is very expensive CPU and Memory wise.

Comment: To simplify things a little, since you want things like "The 8th" filed with the numbers, I would make your massive trim a SELECTed field so you can use it's alias in the results; for example: `ORDER BY normalizedTitle REGEXP "^[0-9]", normalizedTitle`

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you `order by` a function rather than a field all opportunities to use an index go out the window.
I would suggest you not follow this route. Instead add an extra field to the table where you trim out the parts that you don't want to order/filter on and use that to `select`.

```
SELECT title FROM books WHERE discontinued=0   
ORDER BY trimmed_title ASC, year_of_publication ASC
```

When inserting data in the table you can [add a trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) to the table that does the trimming for you

```
delimiter ||

CREATE TRIGGER bi_books BEFORE INSERT ON books
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    #include whatever trimming you want here.
    set NEW.trimmed_title = TRIM(LEADING "The " FROM NEW.title);
  END;
||

delimiter ;
```

See here for info on natural sort for numbers: [Natural Sort in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql)