# Mysql Sorting mixed strings of letters and numbers, letters before numbers

Tags: mysql

I have a varchar field that I need to sort alphanumerically but any letter must sort before all numbers. So any time a letter is sorted against a number anywhere in the string it must come first. So for instance

```
11B22
```

must sort before

```
11122
```

I have tried this solution:
[ORDER BY alphabet first then follow by number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418215/order-by-alphabet-first-then-follow-by-number)

Which uses this ORDER BY clause

```
ORDER BY IF(name RLIKE '^[a-z]', 1, 2), name
```

It will sort correctly

```
AAA
```

before

```
1AA
```

but puts

```
A1A
```

before

```
AAA
```

So it only seems to operate on the first character in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all letters are upper case (as per your examples), use a case-sensitive (ie `binary`) `order by` after converting digits `'0'` through `'9'` to letters `'a'` through `'j'` respectively:

```
...
order by binary replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
  name, '0', 'a'), '1', 'b'), '2', 'c'), '3', 'd'), '4', 'e'), '5', 'f'), '6', 'g'), '7', 'h'), '8', 'i'), '9', 'j')
```

It's a bit clunky, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for numbers instead of alphabets.

```
ORDER BY IF(name RLIKE '[0-9]', 2, 1), name
```

Comment: The regex method fails on this pattern: it puts 11 before 1A.