# How to order by letters then by numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I order query results by alphabetic characters before ordering by numerical values in SQL-Server?

I have myTable with aColumn that I would like to query

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418215/order-by-alphabet-first-then-follow-by-number), which says to try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.myTable
WHERE aColumn LIKE '%val'
ORDER BY IF(aColumn RLIKE '^[a-z]', 1, 2), aColumn
```

however this was for MySQL, which could be the reason why this does not work in SQL-Server. Is there anything like this for SQL-Server with the Regular expression filter? The error message I get for this is:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'RLIKE'
```

What I would like to see is something like:

```
Aval
Bval
Cval
1val
2val
```

rather than

```
1val
2val
Aval
Bval
Cval
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` predicate :

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM dbo.myTable m
WHERE aColumn LIKE '%val'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN aColumn like '[a-z]%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), aColumn;
```

Comment: Great answer, however it also worked if I removed the m. on the first line before * and the m on the second line after dbo.myTable, what's up with the m's?

Comment: @G.LC. . . No issue with this query. But yes, it is a good practice to create alise of table to know where it comes from.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing there will some edge cases where numbers could show up or other ways you'd like to sort.  Here is a solution that should be flexible:

```
DECLARE @TOTALS TABLE
(
  ID INT IDENTITY,
  THEDATA VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @TOTALS (THEDATA)
SELECT THEDATA FROM atest 
WHERE THEDATA NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'
ORDER BY THEDATA ASC

INSERT INTO @TOTALS (THEDATA)
SELECT THEDATA FROM atest 
WHERE THEDATA LIKE '%[0-9]%'
ORDER BY THEDATA ASC

SELECT * FROM @TOTALS
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

What you can do is make a `table variable` and use various `SELECT` statements to populate that table.  Since it has an `IDENTITY` column it can keep track of the order items were inserted.  Then just `SELECT` back out by that order!

In this case I'm simply putting all the values that don't have numbers in (sorted) and then all the ones that do have numbers in (sorted).

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks didn't see this till now