# ActiveRecord - Order by alphabet first then follow by number

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a collection products with the following values for "name":

- Awesome sneakers
- Boring Umbrella
- 420 product

The following code:

```
@products.reorder('name ASC') # I really need to use reorder in my code
```

will list the results as-is:

- 420 product
- Awesome sneakers
- Boring Umbrella

What should I tweak in `reorder()` to have the following order:

- Awesome sneakers
- Boring Umbrella
- 420 product

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418215/order-by-alphabet-first-then-follow-by-number

Comment: Yep I saw it, how do you convert that syntax to the active record?

Comment: I update my answer. Just tested it - seems that's it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
@products.reorder("(name ~ '^[0-9]'), name")
```

Explanation:
FALSE sorts before TRUE so digit values will be last.

Answer (score 0):

```
@products.reorder("(name !~* '^[a-z]'), name")
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I use Postgresql

Comment: I updated my answer. `RLIKE` should work. I added another alternative regexp matcher

Comment: ```@products.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"products\".* FROM \"products\" WHERE \"products\".\"active\" = TRUE ORDER BY (name ~ '^[a-z]'), name"```

First result: "500g Dairy Free Hemp Chocolate"

Comment: Ok, I was missing case-insensitive negated matching.  As @Oleksii Baidan mentioned, `FALSE` sorts before `TRUE`.